# how to apply a function to a given column of a tensorflow tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

say I have

```
v1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=[2,3]))
```

and I would like to do something like

```
v1[:,1] = tf.log( 1+tf.exp(v1[:,1]) )
```

which does not work in TensorFlow.

How can I transform / apply a function to a column?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tf.slice` for pick column from tensor, and `tf.scatter_nd_update` to put it back.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was hoping for something easier than that since after all transforming features (columns of a matrix) ought to be frequently done. Suppose my layer has m outputs, and I would like to transform only the p-th output using say np.exp(). Is it then the only way to do that? (I just want to clarify what I want to achieve)